# Third DataGridView Selection_Changed Event Not Firing (but other 2 do)

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm working with Windows Forms and 2 out of my 3 DGV's display into the textbox properly but the third won't. I haven't done anything different while setting them up though, thats why I'm kind of confused why it won't work. I'm working on my own practice project to review for our final exam next week, so this isn't an assignment due for any credit.

I have a form with three different DGV's, one for Student, one for Items, and one for Pokemon(our class uses Pokemon a lot). There is also a few textbox to display the selected data.

The first DGV just has students and ID numbers. These display in the correlating textbox. This part works fine.

Student Class:

```
public class Student
{
    private string _studentName;
    private int _id;
    private List<Items> _items;
    private List<Pokemon> _pokemon;

    public string StudentName { get => _studentName; set => _studentName = value; }
    public int Id { get => _id; set => _id = value; }
    public List<Items> Items { get => _items; set => _items = value; }
    public List<Pokemon> Pokemon { get => _pokemon; set => _pokemon = value; }

    public Student()
    {
        this._items = new List<Items>();
        this._pokemon = new List<Pokemon>();
    }
}
```

Getting student to textbox in Main Form:

```
private void dgvStudent_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvStudent.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            Student s = (Student)dgvStudent.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            txtName.Text = s.StudentName;
            txtID.Text = s.Id.ToString();
            BindItemsGrid(s);
            BindPokeGrid(s);
        }
        else
        {
            BindItemsGrid(null);
            BindPokeGrid(null);
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtCWID.Text = "";
        }
```

This worked fine so I did something similar for the items part.
Item Class:

```
public class Items
{
    private string _item;
    private int _quantity;

    public string Item { get => _item; set => _item = value; }
    public int Quantity { get => _quantity; set => _quantity = value; }

    public Items()
    {

    }

    public Items (string item)
    {
        this._item = item;
    }

    public Items(string item, int quantity)
    {
        this._item = item;
        this._quantity = quantity;
    }
```

Items to textbox in Main Form:

```
private void dgvItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgvItems.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            Items i = (Items)dgvItems.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            txtItem.Text = i.Item;
            txtQty.Text = i.Quantity.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txtItem.Text = "";
            txtQty.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Here's the problem, I did the same type of code for the third one but no matter what I try, it won't fire properly.

Pokemon class:

```
public class Pokemon
{
    private string _pokename;
    private string _nickname;
    private string _type;
    private int _hp;
    private int _level;

    public string PokeName { get => _pokename; set => _pokename = value; }
    public string Nickname { get => _nickname; set => _nickname = value; }
    public string Type { get => _type; set => _type = value; }
    public int Hp { get => _hp; set => _hp = value; }
    public int Level { get => _level; set => _level = value; }

    public Pokemon()
    {

    }

    public Pokemon(string name)
    {
        this._pokename = name;
    }

    public Pokemon(string name, string nickname, string type, int hp, int level)
    {
        this._pokename = name;
        this._nickname = nickname;
        this._type = type;
        this._hp = hp;
        this._level = level;
    }
```

then in the Main Form:

```
private void dgvPokemon_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgvPokemon.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            Pokemon p = (Pokemon)dgvPokemon.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            txtPokeName.Text = p.PokeName;
            txtNickname.Text = p.Nickname;
            txtType.Text = p.Type;
            txtHP.Text = p.Hp.ToString();
            txtLevel.Text = p.Level.ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error?");

            txtPokeName.Text = "";
            txtNickname.Text = "";
            txtType.Text = "";
            txtHP.Text = "";
            txtLevel.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

This is a lengthy post and I apologize, I just want to give as much detail as I can. I've tried putting MessageBox.Show's inside and outside the if statement to see if it would get there and they would never actually display, I've tried removing the if statement, I've tried using CellClick instead of SelectionChanged and that will display the information in the textboxes, but I need it to be there without having to click anything. I use VirtualBox and Visual Studio on a MacBook Pro. I have read similar posts, but the solutions don't change anything.  I think I've added all the code needed, but here is the Data Binding methods just in case.

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        dgvStudent.DataSource = typeof(List<Student>);
        dgvStudent.DataSource = _roster;
    }

    private void BindItemsGrid(Student s)
    {   dgvItems.DataSource = typeof(List<Items>);
        if (s != null)
        {
            dgvItems.DataSource = s.Items;
        }
    }

    private void BindPokeGrid(Student s)
    {
        dgvPokemon.DataSource = typeof(List<Pokemon>);
        if (s!= null)
        {
            dgvPokemon.DataSource = s.Pokemon;
        }
    }
```

and what it looks like, for reference.

[Sample WinForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T2gI.png)

Hopefully this is good, thank you for the help.

Comment: My first tip: Instead of using MessageBox, learn to set a breakpoint in your debugger and inspect the current state of the program - https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints

Comment: On to your actual problem: Most probably, your event handler for SelectionChanged isn't registered properly. When you look at your form designer, select your pokemon grid and then go to the properties window (F4). Click the 'events' icon, that looks like a lightning bolt, and check that the correct method is chosen for the SelectionChanged event.

Comment: How are you binding the dgvPokemon_SelectionChanged to the DG's SelectionChanged event? From the designer?

Comment: @gnud : Thank you so much, that's exactly it.  I typed the method into the events tab (since SelectionChanged was blank) and it works perfectly now.